# DB Migration switching from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, nosql, cassandra

I currently have a massive MySQL Data but would like to move over to Cassandra nosql. How hard of a move over would this be? I've not found any examples yet on this being done. It is possible right.

Comment: The first step would be to find out if Cassandra solves any problem you actually have. Everyone and his brother is migrating to NoSQL, but it's my impression few have actual reason to do so beyond following the latest buzzword (and don't get me started on the subject of the *cloud*).

Answer (score 1):

A perfect answer to this question would represent a few months worth of work for a consultant. The simple fact that you ask the question means you need to have someone on board with you to execute any kind of migration.

This modification would impact code (interfaces to DB are differents), software (Cassandra node setup isn't the same as a MySQL Cluster, or MySQL replicated setup), hardware (technical requirement and proposed setup aren't exactly the same), maintenance (the 2 software have very different upgrade path), and even deployment procedure...

A standard path for migration would be :

- Abstract your database connection class in your software
- Add support for Cassandra in your abstracted db-class
- Export your data, convert them to no-sql (not a relational db anymore) and inject them in Cassandra. This move is either done offline (no action on DB) or online (harder, need sync procedure).
- finish QA in your staging environment.
- Re-do all steps for the production environment.